# Calculating days using string dates in Python

Tags: python, string, datetime, python-2.7

I have dates in the current string format: 'Tue Feb 19 00:09:28 +1100 2013'

I'm trying to figure out how many days have passed between the date in the string and the present date.

I've been able to convert the string into a date.

```
import time
day = time.strptime('Tue Feb 19 00:09:28 +1100 2013', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +1100 %Y')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `datetime` module instead:

```
import datetime
day = datetime.datetime.strptime('Tue Feb 19 00:09:28 +1100 2013', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +1100 %Y')
delta = day - datetime.datetime.now()
print delta.days
```

Subtracting two `datetime.datetime` values returns a `datetime.timedelta` object, which has a `days` attribute.

Your strings do contain a timezone offset, and you hardcoded it to match; if the value varies you'll have to use a parser that can handle the offset. The [`python-dateutil` package](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) includes both an excellent parser and the timezone support to handle this:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse('Tue Feb 19 00:09:28 +1100 2013')
datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 19, 0, 9, 28, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 39600))
```

Note that because this result *includes* the timezone, you now need to use timezone-aware `datetime` objects when using date arithmetic:

```
>>> from dateutil import tz
>>> import datetime
>>> utcnow = datetime.datetime.now(tz.tzutc())
>>> then = parser.parse('Tue Feb 19 00:09:28 +1100 2013')
>>> utcnow - then
datetime.timedelta(31, 12087, 617740)
>>> (utcnow - then).days
31
```

I created a `utcnow` variable in the above example based of the UTC timezone before calculating how long ago the parsed date was.

Comment: This is great. It worked for half of the list. I then encountered this: Tue Sep 28 11:06:40 +1000 2010'. The number before the year is different than the string in my example. Is there a string formatter for this part of the date?

Comment: @TDNS: That is the timezone offset, and Python doesn't support that (no timezone support bundled). You'll have to use an external module to parse that part; the [`python-dateutil` package](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) has an excellent parser.

Comment: @TDNS: Not a problem, I expanded my answer to cover timezone handling too.

Comment: You're the man Martijn. Thanks for all your help on this question and my previous questions.

Comment: Hey Martijn, I've posted my hack here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553987/python-error-when-in-if-statement  Any insight would be helpful. Thanks.